# Mousemove follow browser and screen compatibilty

Tags: css

I've got the code below working, however the distance from div is not the same across all screens/browsers. Is there another script that I need to bind to ensure I get the same results for different screen sizes:

```
<script>
$(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
    $('#try').css({
        left: e.pageX -300,
        top: e.pageY -145
    });
});
</script>

<style>
#try {
    position: absolute;
    float: centre;
    text-align: left; 
    width: 0px; 
    height: 0px;
    border: 0;
    display: inline;
}

div {
    border: 0px solid;
    text-align: center;
} 

body { 
    text-align:center; 
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
  #try {
    position: fixed;
    float: centre;
    text-align:left; 
    width:0px; 
    height:0px;
    border:0;
    display: inline;

}

div {border:0px solid;text-align:center;} 

body { text-align:center; }
  </style>
```

position changed to fixed

Comment: it has a fixed position